# CSS Error ( width 100% and height 100% not working if !DOCTYPE is given)

Tags: html, css

I went to a beginner course on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2LtZRi6Q0s), but Css is not working correctly when  is given. I created a div class conatainer and added the following css:

```
   * {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      }

    .container {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       background: #42455a;
       }
```

And The Html Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>DeveOfE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Percentage takes height/width from its parent. Here you will also have to specify 100% height/width to `body`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Height/Width percent values are taken from its parent.
Which means you will have to specify 100% height/width to `body` and `html` element (since `body` is a child of `html` and it takes its height/width from `html`)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #42455a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>DeveOfE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu">

    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```